# Can JPG's be imported into MapPoint?

Tags: mappoint

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to import .jpg files into MS Mappoint Europe 2006 ?
If it is possible can this be done by an OCX control ?

I would like to import some aerial photography of an area into MapPoint to enhance the coverage of a small area,

Thanks for your time

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in an easy and meaningful way.

I have heard of people importing their image tiles as pushpin images, and then plotting these across the map area. This should work **but** the tile sizes will be scale invariant. Ie. the image will be messed up as you zoom in or out.

A more complex method is to use MapPoint in an ActiveX control and intercept all zoom/pan messages. Then use these to determine the current view area and projection. Then using Win32 GDI+ calls you should be able to overlay an image over the area of the ActiveX control (use alpha to set transparency). That is theory - it would take quite a bit of experimentation to get it to work, and it is probably easier to use an alternative implementation (or even an open source viewer).